# mongo->php, querying inside embeded objects

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this structure:

```
"_id": NumberInt(1),
"link_id": {
    "1000748": {
        "pi": NumberInt(34),
        "li": NumberInt(8)
    },
    "1002836": {
        "pi": NumberInt(21),
        "li": NumberInt(1002836)
    }
}
```

I want to make a query to select only the link_ids with a 'pi' => 34. I have tried in php `$res = $collection->findOne(array("_id" => intval($_catids['categoryid']))`, `array("linkid.$.pi" => intval(34)));` 
No success. Any ideas? Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I recommend to use the `MongoId` object for the `_id` field, has a lot of options and a lot of usefull functions within it

But that did not answer the question, the query is as followed

```
{
    "linked_id.pi": 34
}
```

Then you translated to PHP it is

```
array(
    'linked_id.pi' => 34,
)
```

Then depening on the result you want you need to use find or findOne